# Insert Excel data associated with unique ID in mail

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The objective is to get a single email, for each vendor, with all the PO numbers for a unique Vendor ID.

[image]

Part of my code. Some body item is missing.

```
Sub SendMail()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

'Dynamic Range selection
For i = 2 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    '1st communication sending within a 2 month range
    If Cells(i, 10).Value = Blank And Cells(i, 18).Value <= 61 Then

        Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
        Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

       'French & English
        With olMail
           .To = 
           .CC =
           .Subject = 
           .HTMLBody = 
           .Display
           ''.Send
        End With

        Set olMail = Nothing
        Set olApp = Nothing

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you making the attachments? The code you have here is set to send multiple emails as determined by for your first `For i` loop and under the constraints of your first `If` statement. Although you have shared code, it is not the relevant code to what you are asking for. Do you have the unique excel files created?

Comment: Hi there, I was not able to share the whole code for some reason. I’ll make sure to add everything tmr. In addition, the main purpose of this code is to send email to certain people attached to a unique vendor. At this time my code is running great. However, it will be a lot easier if I can send a single email to this person with all the information for this unique vendor attached to the person itself. Basically, let say you have 7 PO’s under vendor A and 3 under vendor B I want to geneate single email for each of them and also add all the relatives information.

Comment: @The Gaboon I have a program which I developed for one of my friends for a similar situation, However, it requires that data is arranged of the required criteria first  that means in your case for 61 days. This program uses concepts of classes collection, dictionary and usual excel vba. Sample email output for your case is uploaded HERE<https://imgur.com/DgABUwU> . If it meets your requirement and you are comfortable in using Classes collection , dictionary , I can post my answer.

Comment: @skkakkar Basically if you look at the picture that I uploaded above. You will find many PO's for different many vendor. My objective is to able to create email which contains (x) PO's for a unique vendor. Also, as I mentioned my VBA code itself is running great. Therefore, I am not able to insert each PO's under a unique Vendor in the email itself. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @The Gaboon Please go ahead with your program as it is working great. I just wanted to clarify that program proposed by me consolidates PO's for a single unique vendor and mails to different vendors about their current orders. Only limitation is that you have to prepare data of orders to be sent to vendors be prepared first by separate routines. This program would not be able to incorporate code for preparing data of 61 days range, Please see the snapshot showing mock up data based on your input and separate emails of 3 sample vendors.<https://imgur.com/a/MbiF08k>

Answer (score 0):

To insert into the body of an email, try the following.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

To attach a file, refer to the following link.

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-guide-sending-excel-attachments-through-outlook